# pcap_set_rfmon return 0 as success but the interface is not set to monitor mode

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

I'm trying to write a small program which set my network interface to `monitor mode` using `C`, the function pcap_set_rfmon returns 0 as success but the interface is still in mange mode. I'm sure my network card supports Monitor mode because i have checked using `ng-airmon` and `iwconfig wlp3s0 mode monitor` the wlp3s0 is my network interface's name.

Here's my code:

```
#include <pcap.h>
main()
{
    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle = pcap_create("wlp3s0", error_buffer);
    int result = pcap_set_rfmon(handle, 1);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("failed to set pcap rfmon");
    }
}
```

Since the code output nothing and just returns 0, i don't know what has gone wrong and where to look at, can you guys tell me what i should check or something is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the documentation for `pcap_set_rfmon()`:

> `pcap_set_rfmon()` sets whether monitor mode should be set on a  capture handle *when the handle is activated*. ...

I've emphasized part of that - "when the handle is activated".  All `pcap_set_rfmon()` does is set a flag in the `pcap_t` to indicate that, *when the program calls `pcap_activate()`*, the adapter would be put in monitor mode (if `pcap_activate()` succeeds).

You aren't calling `pcap_activate()`, so nothing happens.

You will also have to keep the `pcap_t` open - even a program that does

```
#include <pcap.h>
main()
{
    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
    int result;

    handle = pcap_create("wlp3s0", error_buffer);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to create a handle: %s\n",
               error_buffer);
        return 2;
    }
    result = pcap_set_rfmon(handle, 1);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("failed to set pcap rfmon: %s (%s)\n",
               pcap_statustostr(result),
               pcap_geterr(handle));
        return 2;
    }
    result = pcap_activate(handle);
    {
        printf("failed to activate handle: %s (%s)\n",
               pcap_statustostr(result),
               pcap_geterr(handle));
        return 2;
    }
}
```

will just let the adapter revert to managed mode when it exits.  You will need to add something such as

```
    for (;;)
        pause();
```

at the end of `main()`, so the program doesn't exit unless you interrupt or terminate it.

(Note: I added more error checking and reporting to the program.  This Is A Good Thing, as it means that, if something doesn't work, the program will give a detailed error report, helping you - or whoever you ask for help - try to fix the problem, rather than just silently failing or, if `pcap_create()` fails, crashing.)

Comment: Your code now prompt root permission for capturing. But i get "failed to activate handle: That device doesn't support monitor mode (That device doesn't support monitor mode)" while activating the handler. Can you help me on this one as well?

Comment: If this is on Linux (as I suspect it is, given the device name), then, if this is libpcap 1.10 or later, it only supports monitor mode if it was built with libnl, and most distributions don't build it that way.